# How to fix vue axios CORS issue?

Tags: vue.js

How can I prevent CORS issue with vue axios?

Following is the code for making requests with the backend using vue and axios.

```
axios.config.js

/// here I'm creating a vue axios instance.

import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com/api/v1/",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: "TOKEN 3413413dfdsfsafd3rr41",
  },

});
```

and inside the `vue.config.js`

I've proxied the request.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api/*": {
        target: "http://localhost:8081",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and inside my vuex store I'm calling an action:

```
import axios from 'axios.config'

  actions: {
    getData({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get(`products/grocery`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("res :", res);
          commit("SET_DATA", res.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("e :", e);
          commit("SET_ERROR", e);
        });
    },
}
```

But when I look at the request in the console, I can see that it is sending request to the original url `https://example.com/api/v1/` rather than appending the dev server line this: `http://localhost:8081/api/v1/`

Not sure why the proxying is not working!

Comment: It's not my backend (its a clients backend). I'm not sure of the backend technology. But still this should work right..? I mean proxying the request (no matter what the backend is)

Answer (score 1):

External URLs doesn't get proxied. Change the base URL in axios to `/api/v1/`

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "/api/v1/",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: "TOKEN 3413413dfdsfsafd3rr41",
  },
});
```

Comment: ok. then I'm getting the following error ```431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)```

Comment: Check the request headers that are being sent. That should help in figuring the issue.

Comment: Its the same:  ```headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: "TOKEN 3413413dfdsfsafd3rr41",
  }```

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt provides a proxy option which you can use to avoid cors errors,
[Nuxt Documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/)

You can refer this for more information and available options [@nuxt/proxy](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module#proxy)